# Adding divs on the right side

Tags: html, css

So I have a silly question, how do I get my divs on the right side? I have main content but I need to set up four divs on the right side. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx5FA.jpg) and I need to add **div1 - 4**. Am I supposed to add `width:100%; float: left` in `.main_container`?

Question #2 - I would like to group **main_info1 - 3** under one div like **main** so that I could use `.main` in css with `max-width: 900px; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 20px;` attributes for all divs without the need for repeating but when I do that **main_info2** jumps up and ignores **main_info1** lists. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="main_container">
<div class="title_container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<aside>
<div class="small_blocks">
    <div class="block1">
        <span>Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
        <span>Text</span>
    </div> 
</div>   
</aside>
<div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="image1">
        <img src="img/img1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
        <img src="img/img2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main_info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="main_info2 clearfix">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <p>Text</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_info3 clearfix">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main_container {
  width: 1360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("../img/bg.jpg") left top no-repeat;
  background-color: #0c0334;
}

.title_container {
  display: table;

}

.title_container h1 {
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 66px;

}

.small_blocks {
  min-width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.small_blocks div {
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.small_blocks .block1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #390b5d;
  width: 595px;
  line-height: 52px;
}   

.small_blocks .block1 span {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.small_blocks .block2 {
  float: left;
  width: 285px;
  background: #e26c34;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 52px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.small_blocks .block2 span {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 100;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.clearfix:after { 
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.content {
  width: 900px;
  height: 377px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.content .image1 {
  float: left;
  width: 268px;
}

.content .image2 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 622px;
}

.main_info {
  max-width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 20px;  
}

.main_info h2 {
  height: 34px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #390b5d;
}

.main_info2  {
  max-width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 60px 0px 0px 20px;
  background: #110321;
}   

.main_info2 h2 {
  background: #390b5d;
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 880px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 52px;
}

.main_info3  {
  max-width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 60px 0px 0px 20px;
  background: #390b5d;
}   

.main_info3 h2 {
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 880px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 52px;
}
```

Comment: Which are the four divs you want to move?

Comment: Check the image I attached, on the right side there are four squares div1 -4. And I don't want to move them, I want to create them but I don't know how to create them so that they appear on top not under main content.

Comment: You should check out some grid frameworks. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) has a pretty good one. Looks like you're going for a two column layout.

Comment: Bootstrap would be fine but this is not a website, just a simple one-page html so it's over complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are a newbie. You should work hard to master in HTML and CSS. :)

However, here is a solution. Please inspect them closely. Hopefully you will get your answers.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.wrapper {
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.title_container {
  padding-top: 50px 0 30px;
}
.title_container h1 {
  line-height: 66px;
}
.small_blocks {
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 52px;
  color: #fff;
}
.small_blocks > div {
  height: inherit;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.small_blocks .block1 {
  background: #390b5d;
  width: 66.111111%;
}
.small_blocks .block2 {
  width: 33.888889%;
  background: #e26c34;
}
.content {
  /*height: 377px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.content > div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.content .image1 {
  float: left;
  width: 29.777778%;
}
.content .image2 {
  float: left;
  width: 70.222222%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.main_container {
  width: 68.181818%;
  float: left;
}
.main_info {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
}
.main_info .head {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.main_info h2 {
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
}
.main_info .body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 31.818182%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
}
.sidebar_block {
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="title_container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>
  <main class="main_container">
    <div class="small_blocks">
      <div class="block1">
        <span>Block 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="block2">
        <span>Block 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content clearfix">
      <div class="image1">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/268x377/000/fff.jpg&text=image1">
      </div>
      <div class="image2">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/622x377/000/fff.jpg&text=image2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="main_info">
      <div class="head">
        <h2>Main Info-1 h2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Main info 1
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="main_info">
      <div class="head">
        <h2>Main Info-2 h2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Main info 2
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="main_info">
      <div class="head">
        <h2>Main Info-3 h2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        Main info 3
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <section class="sidebar_block">Div 1</section>
    <section class="sidebar_block">Div 2</section>
    <section class="sidebar_block">Div 3</section>
    <section class="sidebar_block">Div 4</section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

---

#### Regarding the questions in your comment:

1. Actually `float` works. As you use a fixed width `width: 420px;`, probably there has no enough space for the second `ul` to accommodate it in a single row. Use `width: 50%;` or below and see the changes. Or, you can check it in a wider screen, like, 1360px resolution.
2. Yes, for smaller devices.
   This is a basic example. I used percentage values for the column width. So columns may become very narrower in smaller devices. To prevent that, I used `min-width: 1000px` for `.wrapper`. This will prevent narrower column width, but cause a horizontal scroll-bar in smaller devices.

Comment: Cool, thanks man! Of course I'm a newbie, I think that was pretty clear when I asked such a silly question on how to get divs on the right side :)
I have a few questions tho:  
1. In Main Info-3 I have two lists next to each other with `float` but it does not work anymore, what's the problem? It's somewhere in `.main_info3 ul`.
CSS: `.main_info3 ul { float: left; width: 420px; }`  
2. Why do you put `min-width` in `.wrapper`, is it for smaller devices?

Comment: Continuing with question #1 - it's definitely `float:left` fault. But how do I get those lists next to each other instead of second being below without `float`?

Comment: Actually your `ul` is not 50% wide. It is wider than that. Google for **box model** and **CSS box sizing** to know how to calculate element's width. (and height too). Again, you cannot use left margin if you use 50% width

Comment: Yes, got it sort of working with `width: 48.839%;` but why does it ignore background? You can see in jsfiddle that lists should be on the darkest background and that purple section is for next section. It looks like `float` is still working even for next section.

Comment: This is the behavior of `float` property. If parent does not have `float` and children have `float`, then parent will not grow with children. You should do some homework to find other behaviors of `float` property. Try [clearfix hack](https://jsfiddle.net/bvbg8ck6/6/).

Comment: Thanks, that is finally all :) I was putting clearfix afterwards with next_section instead of lists, that's why it was not working.